# How to set a value based on click of a button group?

Tags: angular

I'm creating my first angular 2+ form and want to set a value based on clicking 'yes' and 'no' buttons a bit like a radio.  I have a solution working using a hidden input box that gets set on click of either of those buttons.

I just want to know if this is this is a correct and elegant solution within angular 2+?  Is there a way without using the hidden input?

My code:

```
 <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'error': newProductForm.controls.difficulty?.invalid && newProductForm.controls.difficulty?.dirty }">
  <label for="productDifficulty">Difficulty</label>
  <em *ngIf="newProductForm.controls.difficulty?.invalid">Required</em>

  <div class="btn-radio" #difficuty>
    <input [(ngModel)]="difficulty" name="difficulty" required id="productDifficulty" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
    <button type="button" [class.active]="difficulty===true" (click)="difficulty=true" class="btn">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" [class.active]="difficulty===false" (click)="difficulty=false" class="btn">No</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It should work without the hidden input. Try removing it.

Comment: It exists within a form tag and doesn't bind without the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Davy, if the code belong to a FormGroup (I supouse it's called newProductForm), you can use a setter (and forget the field hidden)

```
get difficulty()
{
    return this.newProductForm?this.newProductForm.controls.difficulty:false
}
set difficulty(value)
{
   this.newProductForm.controls.dificulty.setValue(value)
}
```

Or you can animate to make a custom form control

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, it is not wrong. But not elegant.

If you want to keep the checkbox, you can customize it, like a toggle switch

[enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp)

Otherwise, the input is not really necessary, if you only want it for the validation